# How to paste only duplicate files?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, copy-paste

I have a folder of DLLs that I am using for a visual studio project, however, they are out of date and need to be updated. I have the updated versions of each file in another folder but the issue is that they are scattered in between many files that I do not need. Simply copying and overwriting the whole folder is not a good idea because I do not want to copy over many files I do not need and copying and pasting one by one in unrealistic as there are too many. Is there a way to copy files from one folder to another on the condition that an older version of the file already exists there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a script (in bash, for example) that copies files only if filenames match.

Some useful bash commands for this task are [ls](https://ss64.com/bash/ls.html) and [cp](https://ss64.com/bash/cp.html).

Bash can do cool things like listing all the .dll files in a directory with `ls -1 *.dll`

[Guide](https://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/) to add the bash shell to windows.